# Is there a way to inform server about bounced push notifications

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to inform server about bounced push notifications, so I can remove remove device tokens and reduce number of push notifications that server send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by *bounced* you mean the device intentionally rejected the notification, then no. There is currently no feature like that in FCM.

If what you mean is to identify if the token is no longer valid, then you just have to look out for [`NotRegistered`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) errors.

Comment: thanks AL. Where should I look for those errors?

Comment: In the response when sending the messages.

Comment: will check it out. thanks!

Comment: Awesome! I see `not_registered_ids` array in response! Thanks!